# OpenShift action audit log

Tags: deployment, audit, openshift

Good day everyone !

I am looking if there is any way to audit or look at a audit log for any specific actions done by a specific user on a deployment for example.

My goal would be to see, who scaled up or down a specific deployment or statefulSet, change storage size or settings.

Something along theses lines.

Thank you

OpenShift version: Latest 4.14
P.S: *I am looking for a CLI example. Not even sure there would be something at the UI anyway.*

Comment: In general: quite often you need to explicitly configure auditing beforehand and what you can seen now depends on what policy  was active during the incident that you're investigating. See also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/pt-br/openshift_container_platform/4.14/html/security_and_compliance/audit-log-policy-config and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/pt-br/openshift_container_platform/4.14/html/security_and_compliance/audit-log-view

Comment: I suppose my other issue here is that I am not a OpenShift admin, just my own namespace admin. Not sure If a specific role to view theses audit logs is possible, if, obviously they enabled the audit logs.... Hummmm.... will get back with more details......